# Objective C: open and close a subview

Tags: objective-c, subview, ibaction

This is my code with two IBAction for open and close a subview in two different classes

```
- (IBAction) showListClient:(id) sender {

if( list == nil){

    list = [[ListClient alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListClient" bundle:nil];
    [list setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:list.view];
}

}
```

and for close

```
-(IBAction)closeListClient {
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

now it's ok for the first time, but if I want use more time my list I must write in closeListClient

```
list = nil;
[list release];
```

now my problem is this "list" is declared only in the class ListClient as

```
ListClient *list;
```

and when I write list in CloseListClient is an error...what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ListCLient.h define a protocol for its delegate:

```
@protocol ListClientDelegate<NSObject>
@optional
- (void)listClientDidClose:(ListClient *)listClient;
@end
```

and modify the property definition for `delegate`:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ListClientDelegate> delegate;
```

Then send a message to the delegate when the closeListClient action is called (in ListClient.m):

```
-(IBAction)closeListClient {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.delegate listClientDidClose:self]
}
```

Then finally in SomeController.m implement the delegate method:

```
-(void)listClientDidClose:(ListClient *)listClient {
    [list release];
    list = nil;
}
```

I hope that solves your proplem.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out a few issues that may be fix your problem. I am a little lost about your question especially the wording of Opening and Closing a view. I am sure you just want to hide and show a view based on which button is pressed.

This code is incorrect

```
-(IBAction)closeListClient {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}

//I am sure you want to remove the list view
-(IBAction)closeListClient {
   [list.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

And the release and nil operations are backwards here

```
list = nil;
[list release];

//Change to
[list release];
list = nil;
```

You should end up with

```
-(IBAction)closeListClient {
    [list.view removeFromSuperview];
    [list release];
    list = nil;
}
```

Comment: ok but i use showListClient and closeListClient in two different classe, then when I use "list" in showListCient it's ok, but in closeListClient I can't use it because this method is in another class, do you understand?